# Can I mix float, long, double values when operating in Java?

Tags: java, android, performance, floating-point

I'm getting some values from different functions, some floats, other doubles, long...

I need to operate with them.

Is it correct to do it without previously converting to the same kind of number?

For example:

```
float distanceInMetersFloat = initialPosition.distanceTo(finalPosition);
long deltaTimeNanosLong = (finalPosition.getElapsedRealtimeNanos() - initialPosition.getElapsedRealtimeNanos()); // nanoseconds
long deltaTimeSecondsLong = deltaTimeNanosLong / 1000000000;

double speed = distanceInMetersFloat / deltaTimeNanosLong;
```

I have much more precision than I need, it doesn't matter to me to lose some decimal numbers.

Comment: Its a very primitive question and probably one of the very first thing programmers are taught during training.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but a engineering student. I come from Matlab, where you don't have to define this. I'm learning, I don't know why you vote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be clear that you are mixing 32-bit values and 64-bit numbers. So you need to work towards ending up with the bigger 64-bit results t avoid losing data.

And be aware that you are mixing integer numbers with fractional numbers.

On both issues above, study carefully how [Java primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) syntax works with numeric literals.

So yes you can mix the types. Java will generally do the right thing. For example, multiplying a `long` by an `int` will produce a `long`. But there are cases in complicated code where the compiler may get confused, and you will need to add some explicit casts such as `( long )`. Any basic intro-to-Java book or the Oracle Tutorial will walk you though this.

Tips:

- Append an `L` to `long` literals.
- Append `f` to `float` literals. And `d` to `double` literals.
- Use underscores to group your digits for easier reading. Ex: `1_000_000`

Lastly, be aware that `float` and `double` are both floating-point numbers. [Floating-point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) technology trades off accuracy for performance. This is good for rendering curves in a drawing or rendering a game, but bad for money or other values where you don't want extraneous extra digits in your decimal fraction.

## `BigDecimal`

If accuracy matters, I would convert all your values to [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) objects rather than primitives. `BigDecimal` eschews floating-point. Much slower, but accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to attempt to guess what you want.
The important parts are these:

1. You must perform the math operation using as high a precision as you
   have. So in this case your original code is actually fine (though speed is a `double` which is right now useless unless you make `distanceInMetersFloat`also a `double`).
2. Once you have    `speed` you can then convert it to whatever precision you want using     whatever rounding mode you wish. For details on how to accomplish
   this in java see answer     [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

**float** and **ints** are 32 bits primitives, so if you want to make a Salad, prepare the bowl to hold them all? (**double** and **long**), additionally for that, longs and ints are whole numbers, so you must carefully and explicitly cast the numbers otherwise you will get weird results...